Changing default Flowbite-React color
I'm currently working on a project in Astro, using the Flowbite Tailwind component library along with Flowbite React. My question is: how can I change the default cyan-500 color in Flowbite React to match the blue shade used in Flowbite Tailwind components? I tried updating the color in tailwind.config, but it didn’t work because Flowbite React inserts the plugin directly in the configuration, leaving me with no control over it. Thanks in advance for any help!
